# convert codeigniter query Active Record Class

Tags: codeigniter

I have a query which I am trying to convert to the codeigniter active database records. Rather than using query row which is to long.

What is best way to make this As a Active Record Class?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, (SELECT ug.name FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group`ug 
WHERE ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id) 
AS user_group FROM `" . 
$this->db->dbprefix . "user` u 
WHERE u.user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'");

return $query->row_array();
```

Not sure if correct

```
$this->db->select('ug.name');
    $this->db->from('user_group', 'ug');
    $this->db->where('ug.user_group_id', 'u.user_group_id');
    $this->db->from('user', 'u');
    $this->db->where('u.user_id', (int)$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use a mysql join in your case.

So in Active record it's like:

```
$this->db->select('u.*, ug.name');
$this->db->from('users', u);
$this->db->join('user_group as ug', 'ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id');
$this->db->where('u.user_id', (int)$user_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row_array();
```